# Bug in html5 slideshow in html5rocks.com

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am trying to use http://studio.html5rocks.com/samples/slides/index.html for a website. While it works perfectly in Firefox but when I use this in chrome, the slide does not move forward when I press the right arrow key. I have to first press the left arrow key and only then the right arrow key works. I tried to check its javascript also, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Is it a cross browser compatibility issue ? Also, since html5rocks.com has so many folks from Google contributing there, examples should at least work well on Google Chrome.

Comment: i doubt if html5 rocks is a Google venture though the slide show that it use is one that few googlers developed for a Presentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that URL may be the location of an older version of their slide template.

Here is a more recent version that doesn't have a bug: http://slides.html5rocks.com/

Comment: Yes, the recent version does not have the bug. But, the one given in the samples section is not updated. I hope they update it soon so that others can use it too.

Comment: If you hover over the "? Info" button at the [location of that template](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck) they recommend you use the [newer version](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck) anyway. So if you're wanting a slides template, just use the newer one.